# Making a hyperlink for Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, ionic-framework

I am working on a mobile site. I have created a hyperlink that works and was written in basic javascript.

```
'<a href="#/app/tabs/tours/'+$scope.tourmarkers[i]._id+'">Go to Tour info </a>'
```

This code works fine. But I wanted to change the code too better work with angularjs. I tried rewriting it just as...

```
'<a ng-href="/tours/'+$scope.tourmarkers[i]._id+'">Go to Tour info </a>'
```

where i cut off part of the of the url that was already being used. I changed the href by adding  the ng in front. But I do not feel this is an angular statement. How can i make my original hyperlink be written for angularjs??

Comment: just type *ng-href* and keep the url same. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23811728/5686100

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <a ng-href="/tours/{{$scope.tourmarkers[i]._id}}">Go to Tour info </a>
```

OR

in your controller

```
$scope.path = '/tours/' + $scope.tourmarkers[i]._id
```

now in view

```
'<a ng-href="{{path}}">Go to Tour info </a>'
```

since ng-href binds dynamically

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a ng-href="{{'/tours/' + $scope.tourmarkers[i]._id}}">Go to Tour info </a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow . While this answer may provide a solution , can you explain why and how ? That way you would be helping a lot more